# C++ - Managing References in Disk Based Vector

Tags: c++, vector, reference, polymorphism, disk-io

I am developing a set of vector classes that all derived from an abstract vector. I am doing this so that in our software that makes use of these vectors, we can quickly switch between the vectors without any code breaking (or at least minimize failures, but my goal is full compatibility). All of the vectors match.

I am working on a Disk Based Vector that mostly conforms to match the STL Vector implementation. I am doing this because we need to handle large out of memory files that contain various formats of data. The Disk Vector handles data read/write to disk by using template specialization/polymorphism of serialization and deserialization classes. The data serialization and deserialization has been tested, and it works (up to now). My problem occurs when dealing with references to the data.

For example,

Given a DiskVector `dv`, a call to `dv[10]` would get a point to a spot on disk, then seek there, read out the char stream. This stream gets passed to a deserializor which converts the byte stream into the appropriate data type. Once I have the value, I my return it.

This is where I run into a problem. In the STL, they return it as a reference, so in order to match their style, I need to return a reference. What I do it store the value in an unordered_map with the given index (in this example, 10). Then I return a reference to the value in the unordered_map.

If this continues without cleanup, then the purpose of the DiskVector is lost because all the data just gets loaded into memory, which is bad due to data size. So I clean up this map by deleting the indexes later on when other calls are made. Unfortunately, if a user decided to store this reference for a long time, and then it gets deleted in the DiskVector, we have a problem.

So my questions

- Is there a way to see if any other references to a certain instance are in use?
- Is there a better way to solve this while still maintaining the polymorphic style for reasons described at the beginning?
- Is it possible to construct a special class that would behave as a reference, but handle the disk IO dynamically so I could just return that instead?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: Instead of returning references, you could return an object that has an `operator T()` and an `operator=(T const &)`. This means you could mostly use this object as if it were an instance of the data. You would construct this object with an offset into the file, so the `operator T()` would be a proxy to reading the data from disk and the `operator=(T const &)` would be a proxy to writing the data to disk.

Comment: And yes, there is precedent for returning wrapper objects instead of an actual C++ reference in [the `vector<bool>` specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I will get it to work and post the solution details.

Comment: Another question. What function/operator definitions do I need to make it work with the following operations? `ref.someFunction()` and `data_type * p = &ref` where that `.someFunction()` can modify the data. Is it `operator data_type& ();`. I found something similar [HERE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: There's nothing you can use to make that syntax work directly. If you did `data_type & ref = *(container.front())` for example then the proxy object is a temporary that will go away at the end of the expression, resulting in a dangling reference. Additionally, note that mutating the data object directly won't affect what is stored on disk unless the `data_type` class has some plumbing to report this back to the collection. A workaround would be to have the proxy object allow obtaining a `const data_type &`, then you would have to copy the data, mutate it, and assign it back to the proxy.

Comment: Obviously for large data structures that won't be optimal. You may have to make your `data_type` class able to report changes somehow in order to allow mutations to be automatically recorded to disk.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, the proxy should just return `data_type` objects by value. Move construction / RVO will prevent copies. But you'll still have to go through the "obtain copy, change data, assign back to proxy" exercise in order to get things written to disk. (Again, unless your data objects have a mechanism through which you can observe changes from the proxy object.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I came up with a solution, perhaps inefficient, but I care more about seamless compatibility than efficiency. When a reference is made, it points to a data_type in the RandomArray class. When the reference is "accessed", it causes the pointed to data_type to be filled. Then returns a reference to that data. If another reference were opened on the same data_type, not loading would happen because I track it. That way, pointers could be used "safely". My concern is that if the user makes copies of the pointer, then dangling pointers could arise. What do you think?

Comment: Dangling pointers would be an issue no matter what, really... if you are using some reference to an object, that object has to stay alive, no? So it's not really any more complicated than it would be with a standard container, unless I'm missing something. My main concern is how the `data_type` object knows to notify the disk-based collection that its value changed, so that the collection can update the data on disk.

Answer (score 0):

So a better solution at what I was trying to do is to use SQLite as the backend for the database. Use BLOBs as the column types for key and value columns. This is the approach I am taking now. That said, in order to get it to work well, I need to use what cdhowie posted in the comments to my question.